# auto refresh without blinking not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

> mm.js

```
$(function() {
startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
setTimeout(startRefresh,1000);
$.get('pagelink.php', function(data) {
    $('#content_div_id').html(data);
});
}
```

> pagelink.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mm.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="content_div_id">
<h1>sssd</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I used above script to auto refresh a page without blinking, its not working. If I change sentence in  using text editor and save. It will not auto refresh or change the value until I refresh manually.

Comment: Are you importing jQuery?

Comment: This could be due to sever-caching of the .php file. Also, unless there is some server-side code in your .php file, it shouldn't be a .php file at all, it should be an .html file.

Comment: yes.... I guess it can auto refresh page anytime value changes